# Using pytest SubRequest inside a fixture parameter

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

`PARAMS = {"good": [1], "bad": [2]}`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def fixture_good(request: SubRequest) -> List[str]:
    good_ans = []
    try:
       good_ans = request.param['good'] # Error Here
    except AttributeError:
       pass
    return good_ans
```

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def fixture_bad(request: SubRequest) -> List[str]:
    bad_ans = []
    try:
       bad_ans = request.param['bad']  # Error Here
    except AttributeError:
       pass
    return bad_ans
```

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def fixture_main(request:SubRequest, fixture_good: List[str], fixture_bad: List[str]) -> MagicMock:
    print(request.param)  # Prints PARAMS
    mock = MagicMock()
    mock.doSomethingBad = MagicMock(return_value=fixture_bad)
    mock.doSomethingGood = MagicMock(return_value=fixture_good)
    return mock
```

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_main', [PARAMS], indirect=True)
def test_something(fixture_main: MagicMock) -> None:
```

I would like to access request object of fixture_main into fixture_good and fixture_bad. How can I do that.

Right now, it gives `AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param'`